# iPhone: unable to start simple application

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to make an iPhone app here, and I've gotten it down to a simple HelloWorld problem.  For some reason, the following does not work in XCode 4.4.  I'd really appreciate figuring out what's going on.

I follow these steps:

1. Start an 'empty project' type
2. Name it
3. Add in a new objective-c class with a .xib.  Say this new view controller is StartViewController, so I now have StartViewController .xib, .h, and .m.
4. Check: file's owner for the .xib matches the .h file.  It does in IB.
5. Change the background of the .xib to something other than black (I like stripes).
6. Add these lines to the main app delegate:

## import "StartViewController.h"

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   StartViewController* theController = [[StartViewController alloc]init];
   [self.window addSubview:theController.view];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
 }
```

And the app immediately crashes on running with:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:]` loaded the "StartView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

How can I make it work?

**EDIT**: PS, I have no idea why the code formatting appears to have failed.  I was under the impression that it was just four spaces at the beginning of a line...

Comment: How did you set up the view for the StartViewController?  Using IB?  Storyboard?

Comment: IB.  I'm avoiding storyboards, since they seem to involve files that I can't edit and cause me all kinds of pain.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, but whatever.
You should check out the beginner Apple documentation, because the recommended way to do this is a little different.

Does your nib have its file owner set to the view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering this because it's so ludicrous.

Turns out that order matters.

I deleted the old controlling files, and then added 'startingviewcontroller', edited the appdelegate function to be startingviewcontroller, then it all works.  Not sure why that should matter, but hey.

Answer (score 0):

Do what am error tells you to do. Set an outlet for Startview in your VC.

Comment: There may be many things, I need to guess. Did you create your nib separately ?